# NullPointerException in getView in ListView with multiple views in Android

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I know there are lots and lots of questions like the one that I'm going to ask, however, none of them can give me a solution. I've read blogs and questions here, but no luck. I have a ListView in Android, and I want to display some news with two types of views/layouts: one for news that have pictures, and another one for news that don't have (only text),so the app can display something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5ObB.png). But everytime I run my app I am getting an error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(3973): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(3973): Process: com.example.test23, PID: 3973
E/AndroidRuntime(3973): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(3973): at com.example.test23.ItemAdapter.getView(ItemAdapter.java:80)
E/AndroidRuntime(3973): at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
E/AndroidRuntime(3973): at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
```

I am implementing the methods `getItemViewType` and `getViewTypeCount()`. I've implemented the famous `ViewHolder` but no luck either. Right now this is the Adapter class (cause I've changed it plenty of times):

```
public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnItemClickListener {
    Item item = null;
    private ArrayList<Item> news = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private static final int NO_PICTURE_VIEW = 0;
    private static final int PICTURE_VIEW = 1;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
        super();
        news.addAll(items);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return news.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Item getItem(int index) {
        return getItem(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int index) {
        return index;
    }

    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Item article = news.get(position);
        if (article.getImageUrl() != null && !article.getImageUrl().equals("")
                && article.getImageUrl().indexOf("no_pic.png") == -1)
            // if there's no pic ?
            // TYPE_SEPARATOR
            // :
                                                            // TYPE_ITEM;
            return NO_PICTURE_VIEW;
        else
            return PICTURE_VIEW;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        item = news.get(index);
        int type = getItemViewType(index);
        int resource;
        if (type == NO_PICTURE_VIEW) {
            resource = R.layout.item_no_picture_list;
        } else {
            resource = R.layout.item_picture_list;
        }
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
            TextView titleView = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.titleArticle);
            titleView.setText(item.getTitle());// this is the line that gives me
                                                // the nullpointerexception
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(...) {
    }
}
```

The layouts of both views are ok, I've tested them and no problem. I don't want like a separator, like I've seen on other blogs, I just want to be able to display both view for the same type of information, which is an array. If you need more info or more pieces of code, let me know. Any help or info is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE here are the two layouts, for new with pics:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageItem"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:contentDescription="Descripción del contenido de la imagen"
    android:src="@drawable/rr_logo"/>
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
         <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/titleArticle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

For news with no pics:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/itemNoPicture" >
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/titleNoPicture"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What line is this `com.example.test23.ItemAdapter.getView(ItemAdapter.java:80)`?

Comment: Can you post both layouts?

Comment: I posted on the code
 titleView.setText(item.getTitle());// this is the line that gives me the nullpointerexception

Comment: Not an answer but your `getView()` logic is wrong. Only inflate the layout inside `if(view==null)` block. Do not set values here, close if block and then set values e.g. `setText()` etc.

Comment: Isn't your logic backwards in `getItemViewType`?  If the article has an imageURL that isn't empty or `no_pic.png` then shouldn't you return `PICTURE_VIEW`?

Comment: @ashishduh  The  "no_pic.png" was set automatically to those news without a picture, since I am parsing from an xml. So intead of having null in those news without a picture, with the no_pic tag I know that those news don't have a default image

Comment: @fedepaol I just posted the layouts =)

Comment: I'm saying your logic is backwards, your code is saying that if there **is** a picture, then return `NO_PICTURE_VIEW`.

Comment: @ashishduh yes, sorry. I though you were saying about the no_pic,but  I ran the app, and it was all backwards. I fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two reasons you could get the error

1) In either one of the layout files (`item_no_picture_list` or `item_picture_list`) there is no child with id `titleArticle`

2) The item in your arrayList news at index `index` is null

Check whichever is the case.. You can use Logs.. Write below code above the line which is causing error..

```
if(item == null)
    Log.i("WhoIsNull", "item");
if(titleView == null)
    Log.i("WhoIsNull", "titleView");
```

Comment: And as you have updated the layouts I can clearly see the problem.. your second layout does not have any textView with id `titleArticle`..